# Vertical CollectionView inside an horizontal CollectionView Swift iOs

Tags: ios, swift, android-viewpager, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am an Android dev trying to learn iOs development.

I am trying to implement a vertical scrolling UI inside an horizontal paging scroller (Like a RecyclerView inside a ViewPager).

I know I should use nested UICollectionView, I saw [this tutorial](https://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell-in-swift/) doing similar stuff, however, it uses UITableView to create the reversed layout style (Horizontal scroll inside vertical scroll).

Can you tell me the best practice to implement this kind of layout? Is there any tutorial out there? I wasn't able to find really much (most stuff was regarding the reversed layout)

Thanks

Comment: Will the horizontal scrolling be full screen or will you see more than one 'vertical scroller' on the screen at once? If there is only one per page, full screen, then you should look into `UIPageViewController`

Comment: You can just put vertically scrolling collection view inside the cell of a horizontally scrolling collection view. Make the horizontal scrolling view's cells the height of the view.

Answer (score 0):

edited:
1: if you want couple main pages you should implement uipageviewcontroller, to be able paging horizontally

2: if you want a lot reusable cells paging horizontally you should implement UICollectionViewController

if you need vertical scroll functionality inside every page/cells depends if you want paging/scrolling with many cells (you should use collection view) or scrolling some content like text or so (you want to use scrollview). And then you need to put UICollectionView/UIScrollView as a subview on your pages(uipageviewcontroller) / cells(collectionView)

btw. adding vertical scrolling if you need collectionviewcontroller would be bad idea, because you'd have many scrollviews within many cells

Comment: I would not have assumed that that when he said "paging scroller" that he meant `UIPageViewController`. I assume he's talking about nested collection views with paging turned on in one and/or the other. No `UIPageViewController` involved here, methinks.

Comment: yes but he wants "vertical scrolling UI inside an horizontal paging scroller"

Comment: All I'm saying is that "horizontal paging scroller" does not necessarily mean page view controller. You can achieve the same by just turning on paging in your horizontal scrolling collection view. But, of course, you're right, that you could do this with page view controller. It just seems to unnecessarily complicate the scenario. And given that he asked for "Vertical CollectionView inside an horizontal CollectionView", I'm not sure why you introduced page view controller into the conversation.

Comment: Hey @Rob! Speaking on the aspect of Horizontal UICollectionView (with paging) that each cell has Vertical UICollectionViewCell. I've just you an email (business inquiry) through your contact page at your website. I'd love if you can take a look, thanks. Roi!